# Ios created mp4 video not working on Android

Tags: android, ios, iphone, video, compatibility

in my iOS app I create mp4 videos with these details:

```
IPHONE

Metadata:
major_brand     : mp42
minor_version   : 1
compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
creation_time   : 2015-05-23 05:59:42
Duration: 00:00:02.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1109 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt709/bt709), 320x320, 1053 kb/s, 24.19 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2015-05-23 05:59:42
  handler_name    : Core Media Video
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 61 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2015-05-23 05:59:42
  handler_name    : Core Media Audio
```

However **Android devices** cannot play this video and I don't understand exactly why and what I should change.

According to this [Android Developer - Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core) I expected it to be supported

Any ideas?